# angular download image from php rest API and display it

Tags: php, angularjs, image

I'm trying to use a function to get images from server but no error and nothing appear.I spent a lot of time to search without success and I really need help, hope someone will be able to.

On backend side I have something like this :

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="'.basename($filePath).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
readfile($filePath);
```

The HTML :

```
<img class="user_pic img-circle" ng-src="{{head.profilPic}}">
```

The controller :

```
serviceAPI('GET','files').then(function(data) {
  head.profilPic= 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+_arrayBufferToBase64(data);
}, function(data) {
});

function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
  }
  return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

Waiting for your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: from server how you get image? in form of url or in form of base64?

Comment: I use readfile with $filepath (url of image). But I tried also without base64 and nothing works. What should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

Backend :

```
  $img_src = $filePath;
  $imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
  $img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary);

  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  echo $img_str;
```

controller :

```
head.profilPic= 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ data.data;
```